# How to Add Java VM Arguments in JBoss EAP 6.1.1 Management Console

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x

Does anyone know how to add Java VM arguments for a web application (*.war file) via the JBoss EAP 6.1.1 Management Console?

For example, I want to specify the location of a truststore at C:\truststore\truststore.jks, which is used in my web application for SSL.  The java options I would normally run with a Java application would be:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/truststore/truststore.jks
```

Is there a specific field that I can enter this into in the console for web apps running in JBoss EAP?  Or a setting somewhere in standalone.xml (or some other configuration file, which in theory should get picked up and displayed in the console like all the other settings)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the **Profiles** tab in the console, there is a *"System Properties"* section where you can add key/value pairs.  Click the "Add" button and enter in your VM arguments as a key/value pair, save them, then restart the server for your new properties to take effect.

For example:

```
key:   javax.net.ssl.trustStore 
value: C:\mydirectory\keystore\cacerts
```

You can also [add JNDI properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html) and Maven commands in your pom.xml to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in `jboss-server-folder/bin/standalone.bat`

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/truststore/truststore.jks %JAVA_OPTS%"
```